# InstallUtil.exe deleted when attempting to install windows service

Tags: .net, windows, windows-services

I'm working on a windows service. So I go and attempt to install it on my machine: I open a developer command prompt, I forget to run as admin. I change directory location to bin\debug folder of the service project. In the command prompt I enter:
D:\code\MyService\bin\Debug>C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe MyService.exe

I get some error which I don't remember exactly, but the message reminds me of that I need to run the cmd window as admin. So I restart the prompt as admin. Type in the same command to InstallUtil.exe again. This time the message returned is "Access is denied".

So I looked at the file InstallUtil.exe, and it turns out it is 0 kb on file, modified just a few seconds ago! ... The executable has been deleted has been deleted leaving only an empty file??

And, I'm not the only one: http://ilanas.blogspot.se/2007/02/net-wtf-installutilexe-gets-corrupted.html

Any one have any information on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> In the command prompt I enter: D:\code\MyService\bin\Debug>C:\Windows...\InstallUtil.exe

Oh dear, that was not a good idea.  You retyped the command prompt.  The ">" is the output redirection operator, it sends output to the file that follows >.  InstallUtil.exe in your case.  You got Access Denied because you tried to execute a folder, not a valid operation.  That message is however generated after InstallUtil.exe was already destroyed.  Leaving a file with 0 bytes since no bytes actually got redirected.

Next time, do **not** retype the command prompt.  *Only* type the command you want to run:

```
 C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe MyService.exe
```

Restore InstallUtil.exe from another machine.

Comment: Oh wow, I totally missed that I had included the ">". You're of course right. Thank you!
Btw, I solved it by running the repair option of the .NET framework installation which restored the file.